# Cannot insert character in string

Tags: string, c++11, char

So basically my function goes through every character in a string and inserts each character onto another string so it results in the initial string being reversed. I've looked up online but the answers to this problem seem to not work anymore, I'm not sure if it's because they are from 5+ years ago or I'm getting something wrong somewhere. My code goes like this:

```
long reverse_num(long n){

  string new_str = "";
  string my_str = to_string(n);
  int my_int;

  for (unsigned i = 0; i < my_str.size(); ++i){
      new_str.insert(0, char my_str[i]);
  }
  my_int = stol(new_str);

  return my_int;
}
```

The error given is: expected primary-expression before 'char'
   new_str.insert(0, char my_str[i]);

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Hahaha, yeah, trying :P I just hate when I can't come up with an answer by myself, or at least get an idea of what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you shouldn't specify the `char` type in the insert expression. Also, there isn't a string insert function that matches what you're doing here; you probably want one of these:

```
basic_string& insert(size_type pos, size_type n, charT c);
iterator insert(const_iterator p, charT c);
```

So your insert line should be one of these:

```
new_str.insert(0, 1, my_str[i]);
new_str.insert(new_str.begin(), my_str[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your type cast syntax was bad, but you appear to be attempting to insert a char into an std::string. This is the function you appeared to be going for:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert

> basic_string& insert( size_type index, size_type count, CharT ch );

Try

> new_str.insert(0, 1, my_str[i]);

You also could have used http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse

> std::reverse(my_str.begin(), my_str.end());